# Content in footer is non-interactive (can't highlight, click links etc.)

Tags: html, css

I've used flexbox to set up a stick footer, as the size of my footer may vary in size from page to page. That's all working, but now for some reason the footer is non-interactive!

Page here: http://teamcherry.com.au/about/

What I mean is, the text can't be highlighted, the link can't be clicked, and the text boxes can't be highlighted either. I've played around with it but have no idea what the cause is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `z-index: -1;` on your `footer` to `z-index: 0;` or you can remove it completely :)

Comment: Ah, yes! That was it! I had z-index on there for a previous sticky footer methos I was implementing, and left it on there like a doofus. Cheers!

Comment: Hey, sorry, I've been trying to but the site keeps telling me to wait for a few more minutes. Will do soon!

Answer (score 0):

Your `z-index` to your footer is `-1` make the following changes

```
footer {
width: 100%;
background-color: #2d2d2d;
color: #ecebe1;
z-index: 0;/*changed*/
}
```

**OR**

```
footer {
width: 100%;
background-color: #2d2d2d;
color: #ecebe1;
/*z-index: 0;removed*/ 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your footer is not working because you are using `z-index` negative value. Either remove it or give a positive value.

```
footer {
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    color: #ecebe1;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1; /*Remove this*/
}
```

> Note: Z-index only works when you give position `relative` or
>   `absolute;`

Answer (score -1):

Try putting z-index on the footer div.

Comment: Should have a valid answer.

Comment: I mean add style: z-index:99; in your <footer>

Comment: It doesn't need to be 99, it either needs to be 0 or 1 really.